# Twig accessing protected/private model variables

Tags: php, twig, render, private, protected

I have a problem with Twig, (in fact this is not really a problem but it's disturbing to me)

I have a Post model class in **php** and i have some *protected* variables (I also tried with *private*). To acces them I have a *public* function in php **getMyVariable**. If in my controller I try to echo the protected variable it throz me an error `Cannot access protected property...` so I have to use the function to echo my variable.

**This is totally normal and this is what I want**

But, then I try to render it in Twig, and I use the same system with the function to render my variable, it works, great... But if I try to render directly my protected variable, it works too and this is not really a good practice, **is there a way to stop rendering protected/private variable directly in twig** (I mean outpassing the getter function)

Comment: Oh my god, really? This is awesome, thanks you. I guess I didn't read well the documentation, Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please have a look at the [documentation](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/templates.html#variables). Twig is not accessing the protected variable, which is impossible, but due to its implementation it's going to transform your twig code, e.g. `foo.bar` to `$foo.getBar()` and check whether that method exists or not, therefor it is able to "access" protected variables

---

From `Twig`'s documentation

> For convenience's sake `foo.bar` does the following things on the PHP
>   layer:
>
> ```
> - check if foo is an array and bar a valid element;
> - if not, and if foo is an object, check that bar is a valid property;
> - if not, and if foo is an object, check that bar is a valid method (even if bar is the constructor - use __construct() instead);
> - if not, and if foo is an object, check that getBar is a valid method;
> - if not, and if foo is an object, check that isBar is a valid method;
> - if not, and if foo is an object, check that hasBar is a valid method;
> - if not, return a null value.
> ```
>
> `foo['bar']` on the other hand only works with PHP arrays:
>
> ```
> check if foo is an array and bar a valid element;
> if not, return a null value.
> ```

[source](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/templates.html#variables)

Comment: `foo.bar` = `$foo.getBar()` thank you!