# Translate twig template function in php

Tags: php, twig

I would how to translate this element in php . Element come from twig

```
 {% for option_value in option.products_option_value %}
 {% endfor %}
```

is it something like that ?

```
foreach ($option['products_option_value'] as $key => $option_value) {
}
```

thank you

Comment: yes, both are similar... you are iterating same value of array, only in twig you don't have key value.

Comment: If u want the key in  `twig` it is `{% for key, value in array %}`

Answer (score 0):

option.products_option_value can be translated to:

- **$option['products_option_value']** if $option is a table.
- else **$option->products_option_value** if $option is an object and products_option_value is an attribute and its visibility is public
- else **$option->products_option_value()** if $option is an object and products_option_value is a method and its visibility is public
- else **$option->getProducts_option_value()** if method exists
- else **$option->isProducts_option_value()** if method exists
- else **null**

Not only to $option['products_option_value']

Comment: He is asking about the conversion of the `for` to `foreach`

Comment: And I juste mentionned the part that can be wrong in his code. I don't understand why the negative vote.

Comment: I gave how twig interpret x.y in general.

Comment: Then `twig` is smart enough to reflect what to use?

Comment: I think I [know](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48643435/446594) well enough what this answer is supposed to mean, but it has nothing to do with OP's question otherwise i'd certainly casted a close question flag with that answer as dupe

Answer (score 0):

option.products_option_value can be `$option->products_option_value` or  `$option['products_option_value']` depending on the variable `$option`, assuming `$option['products_option_value']` is how it was defined in php portion;

if `$option['products_option_value']` is an array you can also use;

```
$obj = new ArrayObject( $option['products_option_value'] );
$it = $obj->getIterator();
while( $it->valid() )
{
    echo $it->key() . "=" . $it->current() . "\n";
    $it->next();
}
```